# find an $A$ so that for all $n \ge A (2^n+3^n)/(4^n+5^n)/(1/1000)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

So $1000(2^n+3^n)\le 4^n+5^n$.
I take $1000\cdot2^n\le 4^n$ and $1000\cdot3^n\le5^n$ so that adding both gives the inequality, theorem in the ordered fields.
So $1000\cdot2^n\le2^2n$. This leads me to an $A$ for $n = 10$ as $1000\cdot2^n < 2^n\cdot2^n$ so $1000\leq2^n$ for $n=10$.
But this does not count for $1000\cdot3^n<5^n$. I think to see  that $1000\cdot3^n<3^n\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^n$ so $1000<\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^n$. so $n = \log_{\frac{5}{3}} (1000)$.
This leads me to an $A = 14$ which is my final answer.

Any other suggestions.

A similar problem is $\displaystyle\frac{(1.01)^n}{n^{147}} < 100$.   This is tougher. Any hints

Comment: Kindly read here (http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117) on how to typeset math on this website. It is hard to read what you have written without typeset.

Comment: The title seems incomplete.

Comment: I parse the title as "find an $A$ such that for all $n\ge A$ we have $(2^n+3^n)/(4^n+5^n)<1/1000$". The solution makes sense enough. Now, the actual posed question is "a similar problem" about the inequality $1.01^n/n^{147}<100$. The latter inequality is actually *false* for large $n$, so I don't know what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Sorry about the last inequality it is actually :  1.01^n/N^147 > 100   so > not <.  Intuitively it looks strange to me. The denominator seems to increase far more quickly than the nominator. But that is it

Comment: I have the impression that it actually means <. It could be a typeright error in the handbook. I don't understand what they mean. For me the inequality is true for all n when considered < 100. Every result is far smaller than 1, least to say 100. ????

Comment: I mentioned it elsewhere. This exercise, and the second mentioned, appear in the handbook, where log, binomials and so on have not been introduced yet. So, it demands for a simple, perhaps although rudimentary solution.

Answer (score 1):

For the similar problem, the inequality is false.  If we take the base $10$ log of each side, we get $n \log 1.01 - 147 \log n \lt 2$ or $ .00432n - 147 \log n \lt 2$  Now we just need to take $n$ large enough.  $n=10^6$ is easily enough.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In a similar problem I end up with the equation log(n)-n*log(101/100) < 0.  Of course log(101/100) we can calculuate (0,00432...). Is there a way to solve n exactly without trying the equation with values: Somewhere as of A=600 and some more the equation holds for all n > A. So it is just, how to solve the logarithmetic equation that intrests me.

Comment: @Ignace:   Generally there is no algebraic solution without Lambert's W function.  You are usually into some form of numeric root finding, discussed in any numerical analysis text.